Should I use char for a signed int in C?
If the integer value I want to store is only requiring 1 signed byte, should I use a char or a short for the variable type?
If the program was for a limited hardware system, I would obviously want to use a char for memory efficiency, but should I favour the potentially more readable short if the program is for a system with negligible effect? Or would it be considered common knowledge enough that a char represents a signed byte?

There is int8_t type.

@Ioan "...considered common knowledge enough that a char represents a signed byte?"  --> No, that is a incorrect conclusion.  char sign-ness may be signed or unsigned.

There’s also int_least8_t, for expressing that your value doesn’t rely on its type being that small, at the cost of some verbosity.


signed char or int_least8_t if you want at least 8 bits.
int8_t if you want exactly 8 bits.


In C terms, char, unsigned char and signed char are exactly one byte. But a byte is simply the smallest supported type. Historically, these types could be less than 8 bits in size, or as much as 32 bits. Nowadays, they are usually 8 bits in size, but they could (rarely) be larger. CHAR_BIT is the size of these types in bits.
I think you actually want an octet, which is to say an 8-bit type. For that, you can use int8_t and uint8_t from stdint.h. These are guaranteed to be exactly 8 bits in size. If the environment doesn't support these, the types won't be provided and you'll get a compile-time error.
There's also int_least8_t and uint_least8_t from stdint.h. These will be the smallest type available that's at least 8 bits in size.

Notably, you shouldn't use char since it's up the implementation whether char is signed or unsigned, and different implementations make different choices.

In your answer, you wrote: "For example, char is usually unsigned in Windows." -- Are you sure about that? According to this answer to another question, it is signed by default on MSVC. This corresponds to my own experience.

@Andreas Wenzel, It's signed in Linux. I thought it was one way on Windows and the other in Linux. I guess I misremember. Adjusted the answer.

According to the answers to the question to which I linked, it is mainly ARM platforms (except Apple iOS, maybe also MacOS) that use unsigned char by default.

I don't think it's the OS so much as the compiler used. gcc-like compilers tend to implement char as signed and they are becoming more common in Windows. On embedded systems compilers it is often unsigned. The key here is indeed not to use char for anything else but strings/characters.

@Lundin, You're right, but compilers are going to be consistent with the OS's APIs. For example, the size of long differs on 64-bit Windows and Linux, regardless of compiler. Still, I had left some wiggle room in the original text mentioning Windows and Linux

Common sense would be to use signed char because char on its own can be either signed or unsigned, so may be totally unsuitable for small signed integers.


char is an integer type. How many bits it takes is defined in the CHAR_BIT.

char can be either signed or unsigned by default depending on implementation and settings.


If you want your signed integer to be 8 bits long, use int8_tor as @Andreas Wenzel suggested int_least8_t

Technically, the int8_t type is 'optional' — a CPU might not support it.  However, such CPUs are rather rare.

An alternative would be int_least8_t. In contrast to int8_t, int_least8_t is guaranteed to be supported, whereas int8_t is optional.

Note that posix mandates that CHAR_BIT be 8

"char can be either signed or unsigned by default depending on implementation and settings" -- I'm not sure what "by default" means here. For each implementation, char is either signed or unsigned. char, signed char, and unsigned char are distinct types.
